# Return ¿fuera de mi función?

Tags: python, condiciones, sintaxis, undefined

No entiendo por qué el error me dice que return está fuera de función, he probado encerrando con {} pero igualmente no da resultados, tambien verifique que no fuese un problema de identación.

Ayuda.

```
def sueldo(cargo):
  dinero = 0  
  cargo = "Ejecutivo"
  cargo = "Jefe"
  cargo = "Externo" 
if cargo == "Ejecutivo":
   dinero = 90
   print("Su sueldo es de ", dinero)
elif cargo == "Jefe":
   dinero = 100
   print("su sueldo es de ", dinero)
elif cargo == "Externo":
   dinero = 50
   print("su sueldo es de ", dinero)

return dinero
sueldo('cargo')
```

Comment: No sé si tu código real estará mal indentado o no, pero definitivamente el que se ve en esta pregunta está mal indentado. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta, usar una línea con ``` delante de tu código y otra detrás, y verificar después que lo que se ve (lo que vemos los demás) coincide exactamente con tu código real.

Comment: En el código que muestras se ve que hay un problema de indentation como dice abulafia. Posiblemente el `return dinero` este fuera de de la función `dinero`

Answer (score 1):

Es un tema de estructura ya que la declaración de retorno solo tiene sentido dentro de las funciones:

Ejemplo:

```
def foo():
        while True:
            return False
```

El código estructurado quedaría así:

```
def sueldo(cargo):
    dinero = 0
    cargo = "Ejecutivo"
    cargo = "Jefe"
    cargo = "Externo"
    if cargo == "Ejecutivo":
        dinero = 90
        print("Su sueldo es de ", dinero)
    elif cargo == "Jefe":
        dinero = 100
        print("su sueldo es de ", dinero)
    elif cargo == "Externo":
        dinero = 50
        print("su sueldo es de ", dinero)
     return dinero
sueldo('cargo')
```

Sin embargo si pones los cargos dentro de las condiciones, siempre va a mostrar 50 ya que el cargo que se obtiene va a ser ultimo dato "Externo", debes poner los cargos fuera de las condiciones o todo caso comentarlo

```
cargo = "Ejecutivo"
cargo = "Jefe"
cargo = "Externo"
def sueldo(cargo):
    dinero = 0
    if cargo == "Ejecutivo":
        dinero = 90
        print("Su sueldo es de ", dinero)
    elif cargo == "Jefe":
        dinero = 100
        print("su sueldo es de ", dinero)
    elif cargo == "Externo":
        dinero = 50
        print("su sueldo es de ", dinero)
    return dinero
sueldo("Ejecutivo")
```

Answer (score 1):

python no tiene `{}`, por lo que no tiene sentido agregárselos al código. Acá la indentación del código es la que *manda*.

En tu código original:

```
def sueldo(cargo):
  dinero = 0  
  cargo = "Ejecutivo"
  cargo = "Jefe"
  cargo = "Externo" 
#la función termina aquí, pues en la siguiente línea vuelves al nivel de indentación del def
#más código
#el return está aquí, fuera de la función....
return dinero
sueldo('cargo')
```

Luego, me parece que estás un poco confundido con qué es lo que hace tu función, lo que no te permite ver con claridad qué va dentro y qué va fuera. Para comenzar, las asignaciones consecutivas a la misma variable, no solo debieran estar fuera, sino que no tienen mucho sentido entre ellas, pues la segunda sustituye el valor que puso la primera, y la tercera el que puso la segunda, con lo que daría lo mismo tener solo la tercera.

Sin embargo, sospecho que lo que buscas es lanzar tu función para los diferentes puestos.

Te sugiero declarar la función así:

```
def calcularSueldo(cargo):
    dinero = 0
    if cargo == "Ejecutivo":
        dinero = 90
    elif cargo == "Jefe":
        dinero = 100
    elif cargo == "Externo":
        dinero = 50
    return dinero
```

Y luego podrías invocarla de esta manera:

```
cargo = "Ejecutivo"
print(f"su sueldo como {cargo} es " + str(calcularSueldo(cargo)))
cargo = "Jefe"
print(f"su sueldo como {cargo} es " + str(calcularSueldo(cargo)))
cargo = "Externo"
print(f"su sueldo como {cargo} es " + str(calcularSueldo(cargo)))
```

o así:

```
cargo = "Ejecutivo"
print(f"su sueldo como {cargo} es ", calcularSueldo(cargo))
```

Tambien puedes declararla de esta manera:

```
def imprimirSueldo(cargo):
    dinero = 0
    if cargo == "Ejecutivo":
        dinero = 90
    elif cargo == "Jefe":
        dinero = 100
    elif cargo == "Externo":
        dinero = 50
    print(f"su sueldo como {cargo} es {dinero}")
    return
```

Y podrías invocarla sin utilizar otra variable:

```
imprimirSueldo("Ejecutivo")
imprimirSueldo("Jefe")
imprimirSueldo("Externo")
```